# How to implement a dynamic–grow stack with pthread?

Tags: c, linux, unix, stack, pthreads

From APUE, I learned about `guardsize` and `stackaddr` of a stack. If a `rsp` pointer is going to be lower than `stackaddr`, the `rsp` enters the `guard stack area`, and a signal emits to notify the program.

I am wondering if it is possible to implement dynamic–grow(which grows dynamically) stack using this feature. Can you show
how?

Comment: This question is lacking context.

Comment: Create your own guard pages, set them up as non readable and non writable, and then register them through [`serfaultfd(2)`](https://manned.org/userfaultfd.2) to manage the stack manually.

Answer (score 2):

The stack *can* be grown "dynamically"

1. Set up an alternate signal stack.
2. Set up signal handler for `SIGSEGV` with `SA_ONSTACK` to use the alternate stack.
3. When the program runs out of stack, it will be issued a `SIGSEGV` signal.
4. The signal handler can use `getrlimit/setrlimit` with `RLIMIT_STACK` to change the stack size.

`getrlimit` and `setrlimit` are *not* explicitly mentioned in `man signal-safety` but I don't see why they would be a problem in a signal handler.

Here is a sample test program. It is annotated. Invoke with `-d` to dynamically increase the stack size from within the signal handler:

```
// stacktest.c -- test dynamically growing stack

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

volatile int opt_t = 0;
volatile int opt_d = 0;
volatile int opt_i = 0;

void *top;                              // initial top of stack

// signal handler
volatile int may_grow = 1;              // grow stack within signal handler
volatile int err1 = 0;                  // error on get
volatile int err2 = 0;                  // error on set
volatile int hitno;                     // number of signals

jmp_buf jbuf;

// alternate signal stack
unsigned char altstk[64 * 4096] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));

// xprtstr -- print string in signal handler
void
xprtstr(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    write(1,str,len);
}

// xprtstr -- print number in signal handler
void
xprtnum(unsigned long val,const char *sym)
{
    static const char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    xprtstr(" ");
    xprtstr(sym);
    xprtstr("=");

    char buf[100];
    char *bp = &buf[50];

    *bp-- = 0;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 16;  ++idx, --bp) {
        *bp = hex[val & 0x0F];
        val >>= 4;
    }

    ++bp;
    xprtstr(bp);
}

// sigfault -- SIGSEGV handler
void
sigfault(int signo,siginfo_t *info,void *vp)
{

    ++hitno;

    xprtstr("ISR hit");
    xprtnum(signo,"signo");
    xprtnum(hitno,"hitno");
    xprtstr("\n");

    struct rlimit rlim;

    do {
        if (opt_t) {
            xprtstr("ISR test\n");
            siglongjmp(jbuf,1);
            break;
        }

        // dynamically grow the stack
        if (may_grow) {
            xprtstr("ISR grow\n");
            may_grow = 0;

            err1 = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
            xprtnum(rlim.rlim_cur,"rlim_cur");
            xprtnum(rlim.rlim_cur / 1024,"rlim_cur");
            xprtstr("\n");

            rlim.rlim_cur += 8 * 1024 * 1024;
            err2 = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);

            getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
            xprtnum(rlim.rlim_cur,"rlim_cur");
            xprtnum(rlim.rlim_cur / 1024,"rlim_cur");
            xprtstr("\n");
            break;
        }

        // stop the program
        xprtstr("ISR stop\n");
        siglongjmp(jbuf,2);
    } while (0);
}

// loop -- recursive function to overflow stack
void
loop(unsigned char *old)
{
    // get some space on the stack
    unsigned char cur[4096];

    // get current stack frame address
    void *frame = __builtin_frame_address(0);

    // get amount of space used on stack
    size_t dif = top - frame;

    // show where we are
    printf("loop: top=%p frame=%p dif=%8.8zX/%zu may_grow=%d\n",
        top,frame,dif,dif / 1024,may_grow);

    // keep consuming more stack
    // NOTE: we don't actually use cur/old but ensure that the compiler won't
    // optimize it away
    loop(cur);
}

#define SHOWFLAGS(_msk) \
    if (flags & (_msk)) \
        printf(" " #_msk)

void
showsa(const struct sigaction *sa,const char *who)
{
    int flags = sa->sa_flags;

    // show the signal flags
    printf("showflags: %s flags=%8.8X",who,flags);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_NOCLDSTOP);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_NOCLDWAIT);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_NODEFER);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_ONSTACK);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_RESETHAND);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_RESTART);
    SHOWFLAGS(SA_SIGINFO);

    // show the signal mask
    for (int signo = 1;  signo < 32;  ++signo) {
        if (sigismember(&sa->sa_mask,signo))
            printf(" S%d",signo);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

// setup_signal -- set up signal handler
void
setup_signal(int signo)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    assert(sigaction(signo,NULL,&sa) == 0);

    sa.sa_sigaction = sigfault;
    showsa(&sa,"BEF");

    sa.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_flags |= SA_ONSTACK;
    sa.sa_flags &= ~SA_RESETHAND;

    assert(sigaction(signo,&sa,NULL) == 0);

    assert(sigaction(signo,NULL,&sa) == 0);
    showsa(&sa,"AFT");
}

// setup_altstack -- set up alternate signal stack
void
setup_altstack(void)
{
    stack_t ss;

    sigaltstack(NULL,&ss);
    printf("setup_altstack: ss_sp=%p ss_flags=%8.8X ss_size=%zu\n",
        ss.ss_sp,ss.ss_flags,ss.ss_size);

    void *sp = altstk;
    sp += 16 * 4096;
    printf("altstk=%p sp=%p\n",altstk,sp);

    ss.ss_sp = sp;
    ss.ss_size = sizeof(altstk) / 2;
    ss.ss_flags = SS_ONSTACK;
    assert(sigaltstack(&ss,NULL) == 0);

    sigaltstack(NULL,&ss);
    printf("setup_altstack: ss_sp=%p ss_flags=%8.8X ss_size=%zu\n",
        ss.ss_sp,ss.ss_flags,ss.ss_size);

    if (ss.ss_sp != sp) {
        printf("setup_altstack: failed\n");
        exit(99);
    }
}

#define SHOWOPT(_opt,_reason) \
    if (_opt) \
        printf(#_opt " -- " _reason)

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = ! opt_d;
            break;

        case 'i':
            opt_i = ! opt_i;
            break;

        case 't':
            opt_t = ! opt_t;
            break;
        }
    }

    // show the options
    SHOWOPT(opt_d,"dynamically grow stack within signal handler");
    SHOWOPT(opt_i,"grow stack initially");
    SHOWOPT(opt_t,"test sigsetjmp/siglongjmp");

    // set up alternate signal stack and signal handler
    if (opt_d || opt_t) {
        setup_altstack();
        setup_signal(SIGSEGV);
    }

    // test our sigsetjmp/siglongjmp
    if (opt_t) {
        for (int try = 1;  try <= 2;  ++try) {
            if (! sigsetjmp(jbuf,1)) {
                printf("main: ptr try=%d\n",try);
                unsigned int *ptr = NULL;
                *ptr = 23;
            }
            else
                printf("main: resume try=%d\n",try);
        }
        opt_t = 0;
    }

    // set up large stack outside of signal handler
    if (opt_i) {
        struct rlimit rlim;

        getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
        printf("rlim_cur=%lu/%lu\n",rlim.rlim_cur,rlim.rlim_cur / 1024);

        rlim.rlim_cur = 32 * 1024 * 1024;
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);

        getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
        printf("rlim_cur=%lu/%lu\n",rlim.rlim_cur,rlim.rlim_cur / 1024);
    }

    printf("main: loop\n");

    // dynamically grow the stack
    may_grow = opt_d;

    // top of stack
    top = __builtin_frame_address(0);

    if (! sigsetjmp(jbuf,1))
        loop(NULL);
    else
        printf("main: stop\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> This describes how to make "the" stack grow dynamically (very interesting!), but I take the question to be about the stacks of threads other than the initial one, or at least inclusive of those stacks. I don't think this answer addresses them. – 
> John Bollinger

Although the question was tagged with `pthreads`, I'm not sure if OP actually was talking about subthreads doing this.

I'm not sure that this *can* be done for subthreads (created via `pthread_create`). At least not by using a default `pthread_create` call.

Without special `pthread_attr_t` values, the default for `pthread_create` is to `malloc` a stack [of a default size]. With attributes, the caller might set a larger stack size. And/or the caller will [usually] do an explicit `malloc` and pass the address along (with the size).

AFAICT, from reading `glibc` source, `pthread_create` will *not* set up a guard area if the user provides a stack pointer. Setting up the guard area [if there is to be one] is the responsibility of the caller.

But, in *either* case, if the stack overflows (*with* a guard area), a signal will be generated (`SIGSEGV` ?).

But, what can one do at that point???

The [pthread internal] function that calls the user's `start_routine`, the `start_routine` itself, and any functions that the start routine has called, already have pointers to things on that "old" stack [we must *assume* this].

So, the per-thread stack can *not* be moved (i.e. *no* `realloc`).

The only way to [possibly] do this is for the caller to provide an *explicit* stack pointer [and size]. As mentioned, the caller must set up the guard pages (via `mprotect`, I assume).

Although `userfaultfd` et. al. might be usable/preferable, I'm going to assume that the caller must use an explicit `mmap` call (vs. using the heap `malloc/realloc`).

The main thread's stack [generally] grows downward from the top of the virtual memory space. It can grow until all physical memory is used up and the paging disk is full.

*However*, for a per-thread (subthread) stack, the caller must decide on the *maximum* per-thread stack size *before* creating the thread. More on this below.

It can set up a stack (via `mmap`) of a smaller initial size. Once thread is created, the base/top stack address must remain constant.

**Edit:** The following is modified by additional thoughts below.

If a fault occurs, the signal handler *could* try an extension of the stack. There may be a few ways to do this. My best *guess* for this is:

1. It may have to copy/save the existing stack data [somewhere ;-)] **if** the remap below does *not* copy the existing data the way `realloc` does.
2. Temporarily undo any guard pages.
3. unmap/remap the stack at the same address but with a larger size (via `mremap` and/or `mmap` using `MREMAP_FIXED/MAP_FIXED`).
4. *If* necessary, copy back the stack data onto the "new" stack.
5. Set up new guard pages.
6. return from the signal handler [and hope ;-)].

As I said, subthread stacks can't grow "infinitely" as the main thread stack can (via `setrlimit`).

The sizes/addresses in the example below are *not* "to scale" ...

Consider two threads (e.g. tA and tB) that start with a small size:

1. tA's stack at xxxx1000 with size 1000
2. tB's stack at xxxx2000 with size 1000

If tB hits its guard page and faults, what happens? It has no room the extend its stack downward without colliding with the top of tA's stack.

So, we *must* map the stacks with sufficient space to grow to the "maximum" and we must know that beforehand.

We need to "space out" the stack addresses so they have room to grow [even if not all pages are mapped initially].

Let's assume that the "maximum" size is 10000. A mapping that would work is:

1. tA's stack at xxxx1000 with size 1000
2. tB's stack at xxx11000 with size 1000

Now, if tB hits its guard page, it *can* extend its stack up to the maximum of 10000

**Additional thoughts ...**

We probably *must* initially map the *entire* maximum region. Otherwise, other unrelated `mmap` calls may grab space in the proposed extension area. Either `mmap` from the heap manager, shared memory mappings, or even `mmap` calls done when setting up other threads.

So, we *don't* need to use `mremap` to ever increase the size of the region. Rather, we should use `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` on the area that we're not currently using.

If we do this, we don't need a signal handler or guard pages to invoke it to extend the area. Just doing `MADV_DONTNEED` will keep resource usage low(er).

The thread function can (after popping the stack a bit) release the "popped" area with `MADV_DONTNEED`.

Other `MADV_*` options might be better.

All of the above strikes me as *craziness*! The only use would be a [hugely] multithreaded app that is doing *deeply* recursive functions.

But, if that's the case, it would be better to convert the recursive functions into ones that *don't* use actual program stack based recursion. Rather, the function manages an array of structs as a software controlled [pseudo] "stack". Each struct has all the variables that were function/automatic scope in the program stack frame.

The size of this array can be controlled with `realloc`. Or, we can implement the "stack" as a linked list of these structs with a "slab" allocation scheme. With the slab scheme, all threads *could* share the same slab allocator. This has the advantage that the amount of memory required can be smaller than if each thread had its own/private slab allocator.

So, IMO, *don't* do this on the real, per-thread program stack!

Okay, so that's what I've come up with. I've *not* written code for it or tested it. That's an exercise I think I'll leave to the reader ;-)

Comment: This describes how to make "the" stack grow dynamically (very interesting!), but I take the question to be about the stacks of threads other than the initial one, or at least inclusive of those stacks.  I don't think this answer addresses them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger At first I didn't think subthreads _could_ do this. But, I've come up with a scheme and updated my answer. Please have a look--I could easily have overlooked something.

Comment: Good insights.  You'll have seen that I wrote and deleted a short answer that says little more than that additional threads' stacks can't increase dynamically because you can't move them and can't rely on expanding them in place.  I wasn't completely confident in that, but I'm gratified to see that you arrived at a similar position -- albeit a more nuanced and much more detailed one.  If you've missed anything significant then I'm not seeing it.